# Saving data from form to database django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to add objects to database via form, but nothing happens, information does not appear in db. Here is my code, i've been searching for a few hours and found nothing

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    import os
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Projects(models.Model):
        Cascades = []
        for d, dirs, files in os.walk('pd/haarcascades'):
            for f in files:
                path = os.path.abspath(f) # формирование адреса
                name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
                file_name_path  = ()
                file_name_path = (path, name)
                Cascades.append(file_name_path)
        ProjectName = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
        ProjectOwner = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key = True) #
        ProjectType = models.CharField(max_length = 1) # D for Detection , C for Creating Own Cascacde
        CascadeType = models.CharField(max_length = 150, choices=Cascades)
        CascadePath = models.CharField(max_length = 150, null  = True)
        ProjectPath = models.CharField(max_length = 100)# for later downloading
        ProjectReadyFilter = models.BooleanField(default=False)# 0 uncompleted project, 1 - completed
```

forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    import os
    from .models import Projects

    class ChosingCascade(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Projects
            fields = ('ProjectName', 'CascadeType',)
```

views.py

```
    class PhotoDetectionProcessView(FormView):
        template_name = "pd/ChosingCascade.html"
        success_url = "/pd/ChosingCascade"
        form_class = ChosingCascade
        def ChosingCascade(request):
            def get(self, request):
                form_class = ChosingCascade()
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'form_class':form_class})


            def post(self,request):
                form = ChosingCascade(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    post = form.save(commit = False)
                    UserName = request.user
                    post.ProjectOwner = request.user
                    post.ProjectName = form.cleaned_data.get("ProjectName")
                    post.CascadeType = CascadeType(initial={'origin':ChosingCascade.Cascades[1]})
                    post.CascadePath = CascadeType(initial={'origin':ChosingCascade.Cascades[0]})
                    post.ProjectType = 'D'
                    os.makedirs('users/%s/PhotoDetection/%s', UserName, ProjectName)
                    post.ProjectPath = ('users/%s/PhotoDetection/%s', UserName, ProjectName)
                    post.save()
                    form= ChosingCascade()
                    return redirect('pd/ChosingCascade: pd/ChosingCascade')
                args = {'form':form }
                return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

ChosingCascade.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chosing Cascade</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the idea is the follow: user create project, by entering the name and choosing haarcascade, but when i press "Vote" no data appears in db

Comment: Any error in broswer ?, any error in terminal ?

Comment: none of them, page just reloads

Comment: Can you provide the `template` code (HTML form being used)?

Comment: Here you are, but I don't think it's going to help you))